# Couldn't find Order in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to build a page to load order id but it threw back `Couldn't find Order`, can you help?

routes.rb `get '/orders/cancellation', to: 'orders#cancel'`

```
<h1>Preview & Cancel your order here</h1>
<div class="block">

  <h1> Order <%= @order.name %></h1>

  <div id="multiple-file-preview">
    <ul id="sortable">
      <div class="clear-both"></div>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
def cancel
    paginate_versions PaperTrail::Version.where(order_id: order.id).order(created_at: :desc)
    remote_versions_pagination
  end
```

```
def order
    @order ||= Order.find_by!(shopify_id: params[:id])
  end
```

Comment: I don't see where you create the cancellation link. Can you show the href that is generated?
Also show the error that you receive and an example of `shopify_id` in your DB.
Note: Since this is not a FK I'd rename `shopify_id` as `_id` suffix indicates a FK in rails.

Comment: @pascalbetz I am trying to print out the order name and id on the page but it kept throwing back ```Couldn't find Order ``` from above codes, not too sure why! thanks for the help :)

Comment: show the controller, routes, current url, error message, sampel data from the DB.
how are we supposed to help you with 3 code snippets and no backtrace?

Answer (score 0):

It might be due to the `cancellation` being taken as order id. You can verify it using debugger in show action.

If it is the case then you need to modify the routes file in such a way that orders/cancellation comes before the orders/:id i.e. the show action as rails will try to match the route in an up-down fashion and the request will be dispatched to the first matching route.

Answer (score -1):

You should have instance variable defined in that specific controller action.
It will solve that issue

```
def cancel
@order ||= Order.find_by!(shopify_id: params[:id]) # Whatever you need to assign.. just make sure we have @order here pints to some order record
paginate_versions PaperTrail::Version.where(order_id:order.id).order(created_at: :desc)
remote_versions_pagination
end
```

Comment: pretty sure the error message is not about a missing instance variable  but about a record which could not be found.